# How to accept new requests using Facebook graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to accept new requests using Facebook graph API? If it is possible without using graph API, then also it will work for me. I have searched a lot regarding accepting or denying new requests in facebook, but did not find something useful.

Please give me some insight in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Accepting requests is only possible via interface provided by Facebook and not programmatically.

While you can remove requests via Graph API it's not the same as accept/rejection of request.

Remember requests mechanism is a communication channel, not another API to consume on application level.